# puppet execute remote script on all servers

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

how can i execute a python script on all puppet clients.

i have added a class for the script to be executed

```
class curp {
       exec { "/usr/src/scripts/curp.py": }
}
```

and included it in nodes.pp

but when i execute on the remote client, it says file cannot be found ???

```
#client:# /usr/sbin/puppetd --test --server=puppetmasterserver
notice: //chkconfig/Package[vsftpd]/ensure: created
err: //curp/Exec[/usr/src/scripts/curp.py]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not `find executable /usr/src/scripts/curp.py`
```

**more edition:**

i have fixed the configissue by creating a fileserver,

```
class curp {
       file { '/opt/files/curp.py':
          ensure => present,
          owner => 'root',
          group => 'root',
          mode => '0755',
          source => 'puppet:///modules/files/curp.py',
       }
       exec { '/opt/files/curp.py': require => File['/opt/files/curp.py'] }
```

}

but the script fails with a dependency, i cant find anywhere else in the log to what it is related to...

```
err: //curp/File[/opt/files/curp.py]: Failed to retrieve current state of resource: Could not retrieve information from source(s) puppet:///modules/files/curp.py at /etc/puppet/manifests/templates.pp:114
notice: //curp/Exec[/opt/files/curp.py]: Dependency file[/opt/files/curp.py] has 1 failures
warning: //curp/Exec[/opt/files/curp.py]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Any ideas?

**resolved:**

problem was /opt/files did not exist on the client servers, it works when the remote directory is available

Comment: So what does `ls -l /usr/src/scripts/curp.py` say?

Comment: This is actually what `mcollective` is for.

Comment: You have forget the coma after two lines :       source => "puppet:///modules/curp/curp.py" },
       exec { "/usr/src/scripts/curp.py": },

Comment: _source => 'puppet:///puppet/files/curp.py',_ --> what does your puppet directory structure look like?

Comment: the curp.py file is located in /etc/puppet/modules/files/curp.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

> Failed to retrieve current state of resource: Could not retrieve
>   information from source(s)

means that puppet could not retrieve the file from the puppetmaster.  The second error is because it won't attempt to execute the file if it can't retrieve the file.

I think you'll find this page useful as you learn puppet: http://bitcube.co.uk/content/puppet-errors-explained
The error you are hitting here is the top one on that page.  It also has some more information about where puppet expects files to be.  The URLs don't necessarily match up directly with the file system paths.

In general, when debugging error messages, fix the first one first.  It's quite common for later error messages to be caused by earlier ones.

Comment: the curp.py file is located in /etc/puppet/modules/files/curp.py

Comment: The URL you have in your error message: puppet:///modules/files/curp.py will be trying to find the file in /etc/puppet/modules/modules/files/files/curp.py on the puppetmaster.

If the file is in a module called "curp" the URL you want is puppet:///curp/curp.py

Answer (score 1):

You should use the recommended directory structure, something like this:

```
|-- environments
|   |-- development
|   |   `-- modules
|   `-- testing
|       `-- modules
|-- manifests
|   |-- defines
|   |   `-- netinstall.pp
|   |-- nodes.pp
|   `-- site.pp
|-- modules
|   |-- python
|   |   |-- files
|   |   |-- manifests
|   |   `-- templates
```

put your class into `modules/python/manifests`, the `curp.py` into `modules/python/files`, and use `source` like belows:

```
source => 'puppet:///modules/python/curp.py',
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a file statement :

> > file { 
> >      "curp":
> >          name    => "/usr/src/scripts/curp.py",
> >          ensure  => file,
> >                  source  => "puppet:///modules/your_module/curp.py"
> >      }

and

> > class curp {
> >            exec { "/usr/src/scripts/curp.py": }
> >         require => {File["curp"]},
> >     }

It means the statement File will send the file to all puppet nodes which use that module.

Comment: You don't need a file statement if the script's already on the system, and you *really* don't need an explicit require, because Puppet will autorequire if needed.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I've always thought that I should use the "require", so I make sure that the function is being run without error.